# Path and entity groups relationships in google app engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine

We have entities with path `A1 → B1 → C1` and `A1 → B1 → C2`.

I need to know which part of path forms entity group. Is `C1` and `C2` belongs to entity group of `A1 → B1` and `A1` is separate entity group or there is only one entity group of `A1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entities form groups based on roots of their ancestor hierarchy. Different root means different groups. So in your case, you have just one entity group since those two paths you have mentioned are both rooted in `A1`.